# Get content of tag value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want know how i can retrieve the content of an HTML inner tag value for a specific ID, for example:

```
<span id="mycount" value="100">1</span>
```

i want retrieve the 100 value, i have tried this:

```
var num = document.getElementById('mycount').value;
```

i have also tried this:

```
var anchors = document.getElementById('mycount');
var num = anchors.value();
```

but doesn't work, how i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag `span` can't have `value` property, it's not valid. Yes, it works, but it's a bad practice. Instead, you can use valid HTML5 attribute [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

In your case, that will be:

```
<span id="mycount" data-value="100">1</span>
```

and jQuery code to get this data value with [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myvalue = $('#mycount').data('value');
    alert(myvalue);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/KhmGL/

Answer (score 2):

using jquery:

```
var num = $("#mycount").attr("value");
```

[jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = document.getElementById('mycount').getAttribute('value');
```

Take a look @ [MDN element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

to get attribute values we have to use getAttribute().

to get the value of mycount

```
var mycount = document.getElementById("mycount");
var num = mycount.getAttribute("value");
alert(num);
```